# iOS - making a list of calendars

Tags: ios

I have a problem : I would like to implement a list of calendars (as in Calendar app of ipad) where the user can view a list of months along with their days. The user can pick a particular day and jump to another view ("day" view).
I am trying to do it by using UICollectionView and putting some kind of calendar (like CKCalendar) inside the UICollectionViewCell.
Beside the fact that there is some problem in handling events from calendars, there is also a problem about loading of the view which can take even half a second for let's say 9 cells.
Any advice?

Comment: Use instruments to profile the app and see what's happening.

Comment: The first time I heard about that. Could kindly please be more detailed?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html